# Error installing matplotlib to new environment with Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, anaconda, anaconda3

I have created a new environment in anaconda navigator and have successfully installed packages tensorflow, Keras and pandas.
However when I now try to install matplotlib to this environment, after about 10 minutes I get an error saying “unsatisfiable error”.

How can I get matplotlib to install using the anaconda navigator?

Comment: Could you please share all error content? Please give us details as much as you can.

Comment: try `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`